# ListFragment: onContextItemSeleected not called after the fragment is reloaded

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list fragment that has a Context Menu.

This is how i register the listview for context menu:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_notifications, container);
    Log.d(TAG, "Resumed: " + isResumed());
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        lv = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.notificationsList);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
        //lv.setLongClickable(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        config = (AppConfiguration)getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        helper = config.getDbHelper();
        Notification[] notifications = helper.getNotifications();
        Log.d(TAG, "List size: " + notifications.length);
        if(notifications.length>0){
            adapter = new NotificationAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.notification_item, notifications);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            lv.setEmptyView(new View(getActivity()));
        }
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then the onCreateContextMenu method is:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
    Log.i(TAG, "Called... create context");
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_menu, menu);
}
```

And the onContextItemSelected method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Item selected called");
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.remove_element:
            Log.i(TAG, "Posistion: " + info.position);
            Notification notification = adapter.getItem(info.position);
            Log.i(TAG, "Notification: " + notification.getId() + " " + notification.getMessage());
            helper.deleteNotification(notification.getId());
            adapter.remove(info.position);
            ListView lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.notificationsList);
            lv.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Now the problem is: 
When i launch the applications, and i navigate to the fragment that contains the listView for the first time, everything is workgin fine, event the context Menu, but if i navigate away from that fragment (i.e. in another fragment) and then go back to it (by selecting it again from an option list) the context menu stops working, and the onContextItemSelected method is not called.

Where is the problem?

This is how i switch between fragments:

```
switch(position){
case NEW_REMINDER:
    Log.i(TAG, "New");
    transaction.replace(container, new NewReminderFragment());
    transaction.commit();
    break;
case MANAGE_REMINDER:
    Log.i(TAG, "Manage");
    transaction.replace(container, new ManageNotifications());
    transaction.commit();
    break;
}
```

And the xml file with the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/notificationsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The first time yes the fragment is called yes. Next times no.

Comment: Removed, but i still have the same problem.

Comment: The listview has it's own layout, and is inflated inside the main activity layout.

Comment: I'm not using a ListFragment, maybe i didn't explain well. The setup is the following: MainActivity that launch an options menu (another listview), in the option menu there are two choices, that launch one of the fragment in the case statement above, the second option (MANAGE_REMINDER) launch my Fragment with ListView but it is not a ListFragment.

Comment: is the android:id of ListView in the xml file.

Comment: Yea is in the layout inflated in the fragment, so when i need a to obtain a reference to that listview i should use: ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.notificationsList); ?

Comment: Ok i did as you suggested, and added also the listVIew as a class variable, and changed the way i'm accessing to the listView, but i still have the same problem. When i load the fragment for a second time the context menu doesn't appear.

Comment: i'm not sure, maybe the problem is on how i launch new fragments? Every time i create a new instance of ManageReminder object. Is that correct? How can i be sure with addToBackStack, that other instances were destroyed?

Comment: It seems that it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: There are no big changes, just removed the addToBackStack call and defined the ListView as a class variable instead of getting it from the activity. Btw check i edited the question.

Comment: Yes, they are in the fragment.

Comment: It seems that the onCreateContextMenu method is not called after the fragment is recreated. I also tried to unregister contextmenu in onDestroy, but nothing.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the onCreateContextMenu never get called after fragment re-creation on long click. I'm going crazy with that problem, i tried on real hw and on emulator and i have the same problem :(

Comment: I tried to remove the if statement with same result.

Comment: And what is the problem in onCreateView?

Comment: When you return the View created by the call to the super's method, it's wiping out all the initializations you just did.

Comment: Ok finally solved the problem. Don't really understand why, by the weay i:
1. removed the super.onCreateView...
2. changed the inflater.inflate line adding View v = inflater.inflate...
3. Changed the line that get ListView reference: ListView lv = (ListView) v.findV...
4. Returned new view v.
Thanks, if you post an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: It's cool. Glad you got it fixed.